# Firestore cannot see data after quota has exhausted

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am using firestore for a petproject, my daily quota has exhausted and when I opened the store to delete some data I see nothing there. Whats happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, you've exceeded your quota and are unable to work with the product until you upgrade to a paid plan that allows you to exceed the free tier limits.

If you feel this message is incorrect, [contact Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/).  Stack Overflow won't be able to help you.

Comment: according to the docs  (  https://ibb.co/g3zRUf ), I can remove files to free up space but I cannot see them, so how do I do that?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support.

Comment: Firestore has started working but what has happened is many of my images do not load, they are probably corrupted

Comment: As I said before, contact Firebase support.  There's nothing that can be done for you here on Stack Overflow.